# jsPDF (HTML2Canvas) throwing error "Error loading image" with JPG (but not with PNG)

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I am having problems upgrading a website that uses an old version of jsPDF (1.x) to the latest version (2.5.1)

We use the .html() to render the HTML to the PDF

One issue we are getting is any time it comes across a jpeg file it simply fails with the error "Error loading image" or "Error loading background image"

If I change the image being loaded to a PNG it loads fine.

This is the issue isolated into the simplest form I could

````
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.js" integrity="sha512-sn/GHTj+FCxK5wam7k9w4gPPm6zss4Zwl/X9wgrvGMFbnedR8lTUSLdsolDRBRzsX6N+YgG6OWyvn9qaFVXH9w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="image.jpg" id="testImage">  
    <a href="javascript:download()">Download</a>
</body>
<script>
        function download()
        {
            const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
            pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", [ 980,  1387]);
            pdf.html(
                document.getElementById('testImage'),             
                {
                    html2canvas: {
                        // insert html2canvas options here, e.g.                            
                        logging: true
                    },
                    callback: function(){ pdf.save("a4.pdf");}
                }
            )
        }
</script>

</html>```
````

Comment: Just a follow up, if I do a test just with html2canvas directly, all is fine - PNG or JPG



  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#testImage")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});

Comment: I am having the same problem, but with SVG files as well. Do you find a solution? If you did it would be good for anyone coming across your question (including me!) if you posted the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I use this structure in my async function. Try it.

```
let scale_f = 0.7; // i scale my screenshots

let block = document.querySelector(".block");
    await html2canvas(block ,{
        scale: 1,
        windowWidth: 1110, // make screenshot like in setted window width 
        windowHeight: 2000, // same here but height
    }).then(canvas => {
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', -30, 18, canvas.width*scale_f, canvas.height*scale_f);
    });
```